# How to select part of the polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, arcgis-9.3

I have a shapefile of the country. I need to select only percentage of that polygon for demonstration purposes. As an example, how to select 60% of polygon?

I am using ArcGIS 9.3.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "select" only a part, you need to divide your polygon to create 2 new geometries before.

There is a [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Parcel_split_split_using_an_area_description/00wp0000005v000000/) for this within the parcel fabric of ArcGIS 10.1 standard and advanced licence, but I don't know if it is available with 9.3 (maybe with survey analyst). I cannot check for this anymore.

Otherwise there is the [Split Polygon by area](http://www.ian-ko.com/) for ET geotools.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will give you a 'roughly right' answer, but it may be useful for a quick turn task that doesn't require an exact answer.

Step 1 - Run the [Create Fishnet (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) tool using your polygon as the template to establish an extent (i.e. x min, x max, y min, y max). Use your discretion for defining the number of rows/columns keeping in mind that the smaller your fishnet polygons are the closer you will be to your target goal (60% in this case).

Step 2 - Run the  [Clip (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) tool to reduce the fishnet to the area of your polygon

Step 3 - Determine how much area is (in this case) 60% of your polygon (polygon area * 0.6)

Step 4 - Use a [Search Cursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//000v00000039000000) to loop through the clipped fishnet adding the area of each polygon until you get to 60% (The size of your polygons in the fishnet will determine how close to 60% you can get using this method). Be sure to capture the Unique ID of the polygon that gets you to 60% (e.g. if the sum of the first 10 polygons gets you to 60%, you'll need the OBJECTID/UID of the 10th polygon to use in a selection in the next step).

Step 5 - This step is only required if you are running this in code or model builder. If you are doing this in ArcMap, skip this step. Run the [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/com/Gp_ToolRef/data_management_tools/make_feature_layer_data_management_.htm) tool create a temporary layer that will allow you to select individual features in a feature class.

Step 6 - Use the [Select Layer by Attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//001700000071000000) tool to select all polygons whose OBJECTID/UID field is <= x where x is the OBJECTID/UID of the polygon that got you to 60% (in the example above, x would be 10).

Now you'll have a set of smaller polygons that will get you close to 60% of your original polygon (the country polygon in this case). You can combine these polygons using the [Merge](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=merge_%28data_management%29) or [Dissolve](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=Dissolve_%28Data_Management%29) tools.

Again, this is not the best solution, but it may get you by in a crunch.

Comment: This is umbelievable forum. It works! Thank you again guys!

Comment: @user26230 - Glad it works. Be sure to accept the answer so others with the same issue can see this solution works. Best of luck in your analysis.